# Unable to install React native using expo-cli command on windows

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-native, npm-install

I am new to react-native.
I have followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSRrxpdMpVc tutorial to install react-native but while installing it is showing error as shown below:

Error:
npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://npm.community

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Saud.Siddqui\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-11-11T08_41_45_520Z-debug.log

Please help me to install react native using expo-CLI command.

Thanks in advance!
Saud

Comment: can you show full error

Comment: send data of this file 2019-11-11T08_41_45_520Z-debug.log

Comment: and  what version on node you are using

Comment: Ok im sending you debug .log file.

Comment: Im using latest version 13.1.0

Comment: sent you the debug.log file on your email id. Please check inbox

Comment: Also, I have uninstalled that node version (13.1.0). Now installing node 12.13.0. Will try and check.

Comment: @SurendraKumarAhir I am also getting an error while installing expo-cli

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...gex":"^5.0.0","detect'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\uers\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-10T16_57_33_253Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

Unable to install React native using expo-cli command on windows

Lower down your node version to 12.9

Its will work.

Comment: Yes, I have uninstalled that version (13.1.0). Again installing version 12.13.0. While installing it is getting stuck on command prompt screen. Please check the screenshot for the same.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Now it is stuck on this screen while installing node 12.13.0 as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: you  are installing wrong verions, install 12.9.0 not 12.13.0

Comment: https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.9.0/  you can download form here

Comment: sure, i will download, install this and let you know brother!